# Laravel notifiction MailMessage subject not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have user notification:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->subject('Test email subject')
                ->greeting('Hello!');

}
```

When I call:

```
$user->notify(new UserNotify())
```

All good. Email send me. But subject not change. In subject always `Example` Why??

Comment: Please share the whole notification class. Especially, is it sent via a work queue? (has `use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;` trait / implements `ShouldQueue`?) Then you might have to restart your workers after code changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Mailable class `MailMessage` in the build method, when you are preparing the mail, you can pass the subject:

```
/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('email')
        ->subject('Test email subject');
}
```